# why enum could not be resolved in JAVA?

Tags: java, enums

I was using J2EE Eclipse Indigo, and I have three class declare like this:

```
public interface ClassA {
   public static enum TYPE { TYPE1, TYPE2 };
}

public interface ClassB extends ClassA {

}

public class ClassC implements ClassB {
   System.out.println(TYPE.TYPE1);
}
```

There was a compilation error on TYPE in ClassC. It complain that "enum cannot be resolved to a type". And also a warning for enum in ClassA, it complain that:

```
Multiple markers at this line
 - 'enum' should not be used as an identifier, since it is a reserved keyword from source level 1.5 on
 - enum cannot be resolved to a type
 - Syntax error, insert ";" to complete FieldDeclaration
```

May I know what cause the error in this code?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I had a similar problem:

> enum can't be resolved to a type

Eclipse offered to import `Enum` instead.

I went to

- Preferences->Java->Installed_JREs->Execution_environment;
- Selected JavaSE-1.6 in "Execution Environments" pane; and
- Checked jre6 in `Compatible JREs` pane.

After rebuild `enum` was recognized properly.

Comment: Man this have saved me twice. Nothing else I tried would get the environment to use 1.7 unless I used project specific settings. If I tried to use default setting (set to 1.7) it made no difference. I HAD to use the solution presented here. And that is with Kepler.

Comment: Still occasionally necessary in Eclipse Oxygen, hilarious that Eclipse can flag JREs as "Perfect Match" but isn't smart enough to know that it should select one automatically. Why not just select the one with the highest version automatically when none are selected manually?

Answer (score 6):

- the first compiles fine. Check your compiler level (should be at least 1.5)
- `inteRface`
- you cannot put code in the method body, as you did in `ClassC`. It should be in a method or in a block

Answer (score 0):

You mistyped `inteface` for `interface`.

Maybe your compiler is too old, so that it doesn't know that `enum` is a keyword.

Answer (score 0):

You must write code either in a method or in a `static` block (assigning static values). Your `System.out.println()` is written into a `class`. Create method and put `System.out.println()` there.