# enum cannot be resolved in Java

Tags: java, eclipse, enums

I 'm havin a problem with resolving enum.

I checked previous answers like [why enum could not be resolved in JAVA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6544054/why-enum-could-not-be-resolve-in-java)

and I did the answer but I still get the error. also followed another solution to change the compiler compliance level. but in my case it is originally set to 1.6

what should be changed here ?

Code :

CellTypes.java

```
public enum CellTypes {
  STRING,LIST,PATH
}
```

in the event of canModify which is overriden

desc :

/**
    * @see org.eclipse.jface.viewers.ICellModifier#canModify(java.lang.Object,
    *      java.lang.String)
    */

just calling setEditor method and setEditor is as follows

```
 public void setEditor(int editorIndex, List<Object> choices, CellTypes UIType) {
    try {
     if (choices != null) {
       String[] choicesArray = new String[choices.size()];
       for (int i = 0; i < choices.size(); i++) {
          choicesArray[i] = choices.get(i).toString();

     }
     editors[editorIndex] = new ComboBoxCellEditor(table, choicesArray, SWT.READ_ONLY);
     editors[editorIndex].getControl().addTraverseListener(traverseListener);
     columnEditorTypes[editorIndex] = EditorTypes.COMBO;

  } else if(UIType == CellTypes.PATH) {      // it gives "cannot resolve type " here
     editors[editorIndex] = standardEditors.get(EditorTypes.PATH);
     columnEditorTypes[editorIndex] = EditorTypes.PATH;
  }
  else 
  {
     editors[editorIndex] = standardEditors.get(EditorTypes.STRING);
     columnEditorTypes[editorIndex] = EditorTypes.STRING;
  }}
  catch(Exception e)
  {
     e.printStackTrace();
  }
```

}

causes an error of cannot resolve CellTypes type
where ct is recognised as enum and its type is STRING

Comment: Please provide some code and the error message you get.

Comment: okay. give me 1 min :D -- from prev answers I thought it is a known eclipse problem

Comment: Post the full code, please.

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
if (ct = CellTypes.STRING)
```

to

```
if (ct == CellTypes.STRING)
```

You are assigning iso. comparing.

Comment: sorry, it was a mistake. 
It's already == in the code.. just mistyped it here

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you correctly, you are comparing the `String` name of the enum value to an enum value. Try this:

```
if (CellTypes.valueOf(ct) == CellTypes.STRING)
```

Comment: valueOf(String) -- takes only string
. ct here is enum not a string